# How to make Google OR Tools Deploy More Vehicle

Tags: python, or-tools

I am working on a VRP project using Google OR-Tools with Python.

Currently, I have a tight time windows constraints, high demands, and the capacity of the vehicles.
When I run the solver, the solver always chooses to deploy the vehicle that has the biggest capacity.
Can I make the solver deploy the smaller vehicle even though it will deploy more vehicles? Because in reality deploying bigger vehicles will cost higher.

And is there any function inside that can allow re-departure of vehicle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another strategy that we can do in the or-tools.
In my case, the or-tools will deploy the big vehicle first as the first solution and there is a minimum number of the biggest vehicle for some 'tight' problems (tight time windows or really high weight demands). So what if, we do not have enough resources which are the big vehicles?
As long as the resources still have a lot of smaller vehicles, I can use 'dummy vehicles' to reach the first solution. The cost for these 'dummy vehicle' should be really high compared to the real vehicle, I set it like 1000 times higher.
After the solver reaches the first solution, you can give it a time to improve the solution. After a while, the solver will deploy the real smaller vehicle and will not use the 'dummy vehicle' anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can set a fixed cost for each vehicle.
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5ff76b487a6c2006326765d6417964599eedc8c9/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L844-L848

2) to "redeploy" you can duplicate the depot and use "reload".
see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py